# Javascript mortgage calculator - payment frequency calculation

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm creating a mortgage loan calculator that includes a calculation that breaks the calculation into payment frequencies (weekly, fortnightly, monthly, quarterly and yearly) and am now stuck.

I've tried a number of different ways but nothing seems to work for me.

My script is below. Anyone have any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

```js
function computeLoan() {
//Prevent the Default Action eg, form to post/refresh the page
event.preventDefault();

var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount").value);
var interest = calculateInterest(amount);
var term = parseInt(document.getElementById("years").value);
var frequency = document.getElementById("paymentTerm").value;

var finalAmmount = calculateMortgage(amount, interest, term, frequency);

document.getElementById("outMonthly").innerText = "$" + finalAmmount;
}


function calculateMortgage(p, r, n, f) {

r = percentToDecimal(r); //convert percentage to a decimal
n = yearsToMonths(n,f); //convert years to months
var pmt = (r * p) / (1 - (Math.pow((1 + r), (-n)))); //c=
((p*r)*Math.pow((1+r),n))/(Math.pow(1+r),n)-1
return parseFloat(pmt.toFixed(2));
}


function percentToDecimal(percent) {        //Change the percent entered to 
a decimal
return (percent / 12) / 100;
}


function yearsToMonths(year,frequency) {
//return year * 12;

if(frequency == "week"){
    return year * 52;
}
if(frequency == "fortnight"){
    return year * 26;
}
if(frequency == "quarter"){
    return year * 4;
}
return year * 12;
}


function calculateInterest(amount){
var interest = 5.4;

if(amount > 200000 && amount < 250000){     //If loan amount is between $200,000 and $250,000, the interest rate will be 5.09%
    interest = 5.09;
}
if(amount > 250000 && amount < 500000){     //If loan amount is between $250,000 and $500,000, the interest rate will be 4.84%
    interest = 4.84;
}
if(amount > 500000 && amount < 750000){     //If loan amount is between $500,000 and $750,000, the interest rate will be 4.79%
    interest = 4.79;
}
if (amount > 750000){       //If loan amount is greater than $750,000, the interest rate will be 4.50%
    interest = 4.50;
}
return interest;
}


function postPayments(payment) {
var htmlEl = document.getElementById("outMonthly");
htmlEl.innerText = "$" + payment;

// document.getElementById("outMonthly").innerText = payment;

return;
}
```

```css
form{
text-align: center;
border: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="computeLoan();">

<legend>Mortgage Calculator</legend>
<p><b>Number of Years</b>: <input type="text" id="years" value="30" 
required></p>

<p><b>Loan Amount</b>: <input type="text" id="amount" value="200000" 
required></p>

<p><b>Payment Frequency :</b>
  <select id='paymentTerm'>
    <option value="week">Weekly</option>
    <option value="fortnight">Fortnightly</option>
    <option value="month">Monthly</option>
    <option value="quarter">Quarterly</option>
    <option value="year">Yearly</option>
  </select>
</p>

<input type="submit">

<p><b>The repayment amount is <span id="outMonthly"></span> each <span 
id="paymentTermOut"></span></b></p>

</form>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Without the option to change the frequency (weekly, fortnightly, monthly, quarterly, yearly), the calculation works how I want. 

When I add the different frequencies into the code's calculation, it doesn't calculate right. Being new to Javascript, I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've tidied up your code a little. It seems to work, apart from something small you might have missed (which I believe was the reason your code didn't work).

The error message also give you some info as to whats broken:

```
Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", // < whats wrong
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",  // << what file
  "lineno": 66, // << where to find it
  "colno": 3
}
```

**2 things:**

1. If you're doing everything locally to the client, and in JS you don't actually need a form to "submit" the data anywhere, thus you can forgo having to even prevent the form's default behaviour... by not using a form
2. Your comment convention of:

> ```
> function foo() {   // commenting here...
> ...can overflow here which will break if you're not paying attention
>   return 'I wont run because of the invalid "js" above';
> }
> ```

the latter can be error prone which lead to your actual script not working (as stated in the error message).

```
function percentToDecimal(percent) {   //Change the percent entered to   
a decimal //  <<< this isnt valid js
return (percent / 12) / 100;
}
```

**Your working code below (updated as per your comment):**

> "And how can I get the frequency to show up at the end of the result"

```js
function computeLoan() {

  var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount").value);
  var interest = calculateInterest(amount);
  var term = parseInt(document.getElementById("years").value);
  var frequency = document.getElementById("paymentTerm").value;

  var finalAmmount = calculateMortgage(amount, interest, term, frequency);

  document.getElementById("outMonthly").innerText = "$" + finalAmmount;
  document.getElementById("paymentTermOut").innerText = frequency;
  document.getElementById("customText").innerText = getCustomText(frequency, finalAmmount);
};

function getCustomText(term, finalAmmount) {

  switch (term) {
    case "week":
      return "Each week you pay $" + finalAmmount;
    case "fortnight":
      return "Forthnightly repayment will be $" + finalAmmount;
    default:
      return "Repay $" + finalAmmount + " per " + term;
  }

}


function calculateMortgage(p, r, n, f) {

  r = percentToDecimal(r); //convert percentage to a decimal
  n = yearsToMonths(n, f); //convert years to months
  var pmt = (r * p) / (1 - (Math.pow((1 + r), (-n)))); //c=
  ((p * r) * Math.pow((1 + r), n)) / (Math.pow(1 + r), n) - 1
  return parseFloat(pmt.toFixed(2));
}

//Change the percent entered to a decimal
function percentToDecimal(percent) {
  return (percent / 12) / 100;
}


function yearsToMonths(year, frequency) {
  //return year * 12;

  if (frequency == "week") {
    return year * 52;
  }
  if (frequency == "fortnight") {
    return year * 26;
  }
  if (frequency == "quarter") {
    return year * 4;
  }
  return year * 12;
}


function calculateInterest(amount) {
  var interest = 5.4;

  //If loan amount is between $200,000 and $250,000, the interest rate will be 5.09%
  if (amount > 200000 && amount < 250000) {
    interest = 5.09;
  }

  //If loan amount is between $250,000 and $500,000, the interest rate will be 4.84%
  if (amount > 250000 && amount < 500000) {
    interest = 4.84;
  }

  //If loan amount is between $500,000 and $750,000, the interest rate will be 4.79%
  if (amount > 500000 && amount < 750000) {
    interest = 4.79;
  }

  //If loan amount is greater than $750,000, the interest rate will be 4.50%
  if (amount > 750000) {
    interest = 4.50;
  }
  return interest;
}

function postPayments(payment) {
  var htmlEl = document.getElementById("outMonthly");
  htmlEl.innerText = "$" + payment;

  // document.getElementById("outMonthly").innerText = payment;

  return;
}
```

```css
form {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<legend>Mortgage Calculator</legend>
<p><b>Number of Years</b>: <input type="text" id="years" value="30" required></p>

<p><b>Loan Amount</b>: <input type="text" id="amount" value="200000" required></p>

<p><b>Payment Frequency :</b>
  <select id='paymentTerm'>
    <option value="week">Weekly</option>
    <option value="fortnight">Fortnightly</option>
    <option value="month">Monthly</option>
    <option value="quarter">Quarterly</option>
    <option value="year">Yearly</option>
  </select>
</p>

<button onclick="computeLoan()">Click Me</button>

<p><b>The repayment amount is <span id="outMonthly"></span> each <span 
id="paymentTermOut"></span></b></p>
<p><b><span id="customText"></span></b></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan!

I have a table of expected calculations, and the calculations seem to be working fine for the monthly outcome, but not for weekly, fortnightly, quarterly and yearly. Are the calculations in my script wrong?
And how can I get the frequency to show up at the end of the result (i.e. The repayment amount is $xxx each XXX)
I've tried updating: <p><b>The repayment amount is <span id="outMonthly"></span> 
each <span id="paymentTermOut"></span></b></p> to
<p><b>The repayment amount is <span id="outMonthly"></span> each <span id="paymentTerm"></span></b></p>

Comment: An example of an expected outcome:

$300,000 loan over 30 years - weekly amount: $364.65, fortnightly amount: $729.46, monthly amount: $1,581.26, quarterly amount: $4,752.25 and yearly amount: $19,160.95

Any ideas?

Comment: @Sharpie13, you're actually very close... why don't you also use the value from the select and just bind it to the output text, (See updated example)

If you need something more specific to each case, you could potentially have a function with a case statement that returns custom text based on the provided value. (or you can use a key value type lookup... but for simplicity sake maybe have a look at ho to use a case in this example)

Comment: @Sharpie13 see my updated answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Any tips as to where I went wrong?